# Read list of lists with read_csv

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to use `pd.read_csv` to load a text file as a pandas dataframe. The text file is a list of lists. It also contains datetime values, which contains a space between date and time.

An example text file is linked here: [txt file](https://jmp.sh/s/q7PvlGfWpbk9Orow6cLA)

A printed version through a python console is below.

The first method works fine but is it possible to directly read the file using pandas?

```py
testdata = [['2024-01-31 10:02:23', 'orange', '5'],
            ['2024-01-31 16:59:02', 'apple', '10'],
            ['2024-01-31 17:02:23', 'lemon', '5'],
            ['2024-01-31 18:59:02', 'banana', '1'],
            ['2024-01-31 19:02:23', 'pear', '4'],
            ['2024-01-31 20:59:02', 'watermelon', '2']]
```

1. 

```py
with open("testdata.txt", 'r') as file:
    food_prices = file.readlines()
    food_prices = [ast.literal_eval(food_prices[i].rstrip('\n')) for i in range(len(food_prices))]

df = pd.DataFrame(food_prices)
df.columns = ["Datetime", "Item", "Cost"]
```

2. 

```py
df = pd.read_csv("testdata.txt", header = None, sep =' ')
```

intended output:

```
              Datetime        Item Cost
0  2024-01-31 10:02:23      orange    5
1  2024-01-31 16:59:02       apple   10
2  2024-01-31 17:02:23       lemon    5
3  2024-01-31 18:59:02      banana    1
4  2024-01-31 19:02:23        pear    4
5  2024-01-31 20:59:02  watermelon    2
```

Comment: provide 5rows of txt file

Comment: using `ast.literal_eval` is very risky, you don't check if the input is malicious

Comment: The whole point of `ast.literal_eval` is to be a safer version of `eval`.

Comment: @TimRoberts do you really need an ast/eval to read a simple text file

Comment: use `food_prices = [ast.literal_eval(line.rstrip('\n')) for line in file]`

Comment: No, but that wasn't the point.

Comment: how does `ast` know the first 2 fields are a `datetime`

Comment: ceci n'est pas une "list of lists"... You have text. It isn't a list of lists. The text is valid source code for a list of lists, but it isn't a list of lists. You should just print the standard string representation of some data structure to a text file and try to utilize it as a serialization format. You should *use an existing serialization format*. Like JSON, or pickle, or parquet.

Comment: For avoidance of ambiguity, you really need to show sample data - i.e., as it is in the input file and **not** as a Python structure (unless that *is* what it looks like in the file - including a variable name)

Comment: The file content is not JSON. If the single-quotes were double-quotes you'd be able to use pandas.read_json()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input data are lines that look like string representations of Python lists. What's crucial is that they are **not** JSON due to the use of single-quotes.

The *ast* module can be used to interpret each line as a Python list. You can then utilise the *json.dumps()* function to convert the lists into strings that accurately represent JSON format. Essentially, what happens in this case is that the single-quotes will be converted to double-quotes. There will be implicit structural validation when using *ast.literal_eval()*. Do not be tempted to do string/character replacement.

Once you have properly structured JSON data you can use *pandas.read_json()*

```py
from pandas import read_json
from ast import literal_eval
from json import dumps
from io import StringIO

FILENAME = "foo.txt"

def jlines(filename):
    with open(filename) as data:
        for line in data:
            yield dumps(literal_eval(line))

sio = StringIO("\n".join(jlines(FILENAME)))
df = read_json(sio, lines=True)
df.columns = ["Datetime", "Item", "Cost"]
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
              Datetime        Item  Cost
0  2024-01-31 16:59:02       apple    10
1  2024-01-31 10:02:23      orange     5
2  2024-01-31 17:02:23       lemon     5
3  2024-01-31 18:59:02      banana     1
4  2024-01-31 19:02:23        pear     4
5  2024-01-31 20:59:02  watermelon     2
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, that does not seems a csv, doesn't have any header.
In case it was a CSV with a header you can read a csv using:
`df = pandas.DataFrame.from_csv(path)`

If you don't have headers (for some unknown reason) you can specify using `columns=["col1","col2", ...]` as
`df = pandas.DataFrame.from_csv(path, columns=["Datetime", "fruit", "cost"])`

If it's an array you can use `from_records` instead of `from_csv`, as you are using `testdata` and it's an array.

Answer (score -1):

I imagine your `testdata.txt` to look like

```
["2024-01-31 10:02:23", "orange", "5"]
["2024-01-31 16:59:02", "apple", "10"]
["2024-01-31 17:02:23", "lemon", "5"]
["2024-01-31 18:59:02", "banana", "1"]
["2024-01-31 19:02:23", "pear", "4"]
["2024-01-31 20:59:02", "watermelon", "2"]
```

If this is the case, this is not a `csv` structure, but resembles more the newline delimited `json` format aka `ndjson`.

You can read a file like that using [`pd.read_json`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html):

```py
df = pd.read_json("testdata.txt", lines = True, convert_dates = [0])
df.columns = ["Datetime", "Item", "Cost"]
```

`convert_dates = [0]` will convert the first column to datetime format. You can check that with `df.info()`.

Please note `pd.read_json` requires a valid `json` format (e.g. strings in your `testdata.txt` need to use double quotes instead of single quotes)!

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work with OP's data because it's not valid JSON